# UITableviewCell layoutSubviews called several times when sliding to delete

Tags: ios, xcode

I implemented commitEditingStyle method in my ViewController, so that i can slide on a proper cell to delete it. 
But when i was sliding on one cell in debugging mode, the layoutSubviews method was called three times which made the image subviews of the cell drawn three times and overlaid. This makes the UI weird. 
I'm wondering if there is any way to avoid cell from calling layoutSubviews method when sliding to delete.

Comment: That's expected, that method can and will be called multiple times. You should not add views in there. Or at least you should remove the old ones before adding new ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think that is the answer. I moved my adding view codes to drawRect method and everything just works fine. Does it because scrolling actions can call layoutSubviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post layoutSubviews code here? Technically you should do only frame setting in layoutSubviews and not any other operation. Do not do any view adding/removing operation in layoutSubviews.